# Как отловить пересекающиеся матчи в регулярных выражениях?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Допустим, есть строка `testestest`. Если применить к ней регулярное выражение `/(test)/g`, то результат будет таков: **test**es**test**. Как сделать так, чтобы регулярное выражение захватывало и тот промежуточный tes**test**est? Как это правильно называется?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `regexp.exec(str)`

> Если флаг `g` есть, то вызов `regexp.exec` возвращает первое совпадение и запоминает его позицию в свойстве `regexp.lastIndex`. Последующий поиск он начнёт уже с этой позиции. Если совпадений не найдено, то сбрасывает `regexp.lastIndex` в ноль.

```js
let s = "testestest";
let r = /test/g;
let m;
while (m = r.exec(s)) {
  console.log("Match: " + m[0] + ", pos: " + m.index);
  r.lastIndex = m.index+1;
}
```

[learn.javascript.ru: Методы RegExp и String](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-methods)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var res = []
"testestest".replace(/(?=(test))/g, (m, g) => res.push(g))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Не универсально же. Если я всё правильно понял. Если у меня такая регулярка `/(te)(st)/g` и я хочу получить 3 раза покусочно `te` и `st`. Как это сделать? В моем же варианте `te` и `st` окажутся в `m[1]` и `m[2]` соответственно.

Comment: Хотя вот так сработает `"testestest".replace(/(?=((te)(st)))/g, (_, p1, p2, p3) => { res.push(p1); res.push(p2); res.push(p3); })`, значит имеет место быть.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, вроде бы универсально - просто всю регулярку внутрь предпросмотра засунуть?