# Проблема с выборкой из строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Проблема:

```js
const regExp = "= +=";

const str1 = "   ==  == ==   ";
const str2 = "    =   =  =   ";

console.log(str1.match(new RegExp(regExp, 'g'))); // здесь всё ок

console.log(str2.match(new RegExp(regExp, 'g'))); // почему тут только 1 вариант?
```

Мне в строке нужно найти каждое совпадение. В первом выводе - ок. Во втором находит только одно, почему так? Их же там 2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы и второе попало в массив?

Comment: У вас тут пересекающиеся совпадения.

Comment: Ага, но всё же мне нужно их учитывать... Мб как-то регулярку подправить можно? Уже всё перепробовал и со скобками и без...

Comment: Был такой вопрос несколько дней назад. `const regExp = "(?=(= +=))";`, результат в первой подмаске. Есть  и другие варианты.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, с такой регуляркой вообще ничего в выборку не попадает:
`const regExp = "(?=(= +=))";`. Два массива с двумя пустыми результатами.

Comment: Вы не тот код используете, см. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944169). 2 ответа (я могу ещё один вариант добавить, но, по-моему, тех ответов достаточно) вам подойдут.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, спасибо