# Регулярные выражения. Поиск подстроки в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь составить регулярное выражение для поиска подстроки в программе на Kotlin. Например, простое выражение `(ее)` в строке **длинношеее**  находится 1 раз, а не 2. Что необходимо исправить?

```
fun main() {
val matchResult = ("""ее""").toRegex().findAll("длинношеее")
println(matchResult.count())}
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код с вашей регуляркой

Comment: @iksuy, да ладно? В вопросе есть всё необходимое.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вопрос отредактирован, когда я писал комментарий был только текст, без кода...

Comment: Дубликат [Как отловить пересекающиеся матчи в регулярных выражениях?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944270/182013)

Comment: @iksuy, когда я писал ответ и коммент тебе, вопрос ещё не был отредактирован. Код появился через 3 минуты после ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вхождения не могут пересекаться. Если надо, чтобы они накладывались, надо уменьшить длину совпадения до 0 или 1 символа. Если потом надо использовать найденное содержимое, можно поместить его в группу. Используй одну из следующих регулярок:

```
(?=ее)
(?=(ее))
e(?=е)
```

```js
console.log([..."длинношеее".matchAll(/(?=(ее))/g)])
```